# Cloud Foundry - How do I access my env variables in my Node.js app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I tried:

`cf set-env my-app MYKEY myvalue`

Also tried:

```
---
applications:
- name: my-app
  memory: 256M
  instances: 1
  env:
    MYKEY: myvalue
```

But have no way to access this in my Node.js app e.g. `MYKEY` is not in `process.env.MYKEY` or `appEnv.MYKEY`.

Comment: Is that the real manifest file? If it is, your indentation is off. Should be 2 spaces only. If it is correct, when you run your app instance, and do `cf env`, do you see MYKEY set?

Comment: Woops, the spacing messed up when I copy pasted, but I updated it. Yes, I see `MYKEY` set under `User-Provided:
MYKEY: myvalue`, but am still unsure how to access it in my Node.js app.

Comment: Can you check with `cf env my-app` that the variable is present?

Answer (score 1):

Log in to IBM-Cloud and, under Cloud Foundry Apps, select your app. From the menu on the left, click Runtime.
In the Runtime page, click Environment variables at the top of the page and scroll to the User-defined section, which allows you to add the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at and tried the documentation available in cloudfoundry docs - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-service-bindings.html? If not please do and update question with error